# Tfs rename file on build

Tags: tfs, build-process, tfsbuild

I have a problem with TFS. Trying to invoke a process that renames a files in the bin folder. I am running into permission issues doing it. I am pretty sure I've assigned full control for the users on build folders but maybe I missed something. 
Steps to follow:
Create an invoke process activity.
Run a batch file that renames.
rename %name% %newname%
This fails. But works OK when I remote in.

All help much appreciated!
Thanks

Comment: Can you post here the detailed error message you got?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thanks for your answer and comment. It turner out we have a very strict and strange permissions policy concerning this. I can delete or create but i can't modify. (don't ask) So what I ended up doing was copy original, delete original, read from copy modify and save with original name. Posting it in case somebody find it useful.

Answer (score 1):

I've had success using cmd.exe in an invoke process activity to rename files.  Here's an example of what I did:

Arguments: String.Format("/c rename ""{0}"" ""{1}""","currentname.dll","newname.dll")

FileName: "C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe"

WorkingDirectory: "C:\Windows\System32"